# display view page with data from two models in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two models **Register** and **Login**.I insert data into these two tables from a single form,I want to display the entered data in a single view page,ie data from two models in a single view.php.

**RegisterController.php**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model          =   new Register;
            $modelLogin =   new Login;
            $modelGenerate  =   new Generate;

            $row            =   Generate::model()->findByPk('1') ;
            $gen_reg        =   $row['gen_reg'];
            $gen_log        =   $row['gen_log'];
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['btnRegister']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Register'];
                    $modelLogin->attributes=$_POST['Login'];
        $modelLogin->reg_id=$model->reg_id;

        $valid  =   $model->validate();
        $valid  =   $modelLogin->validate() && $valid;


        if($model->save()&& $modelLogin->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$modelLogin->log_id)
                                    );
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'modelLogin'=>$modelLogin,
                'gen_reg'=>$gen_reg,
                'gen_log'=>$gen_log
    ));
}
```

**_form.php**

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'register-form',
        // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
        // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
        // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller       code.
        // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    )); ?>



<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'reg_id',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10,'class'=>'txt'));?>

    </div>



<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'class'=>'txt')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>



<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelLogin,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelLogin,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'class'=>'txt')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelLogin,'email'); ?>
</div>



<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelLogin,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($modelLogin,'password',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'class'=>'txt')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($modelLogin,'password'); ?>
    </div>     



<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelLogin,'passwordCompare'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($modelLogin,'passwordCompare',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64,'class'=>'txt')); ?>
</div>         


<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mobile'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'mobile',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10,'class'=>'txt')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mobile'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">


<?php echo          $form->textField($modelLogin,'log_id',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10,'class'=>'txt'));?>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Register' : 'Save',array('name'=>'btnRegister','class'=>'btn')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**Relation in register model**

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'logins' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Login', 'reg_id'),
        );
    }
```

**Relation in login model**

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'reg' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Register', 'reg_id'),
        );
    }
```

I want to display data from two models(that i just inserted before)to  be displayed on my view.php page.how can i achive this??? now i got the output as not set for fields from Login model.

**view.php**

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Register'=>array('index'),
    $model->reg_id,
);


$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Register', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Register', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Update Register', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->reg_id)),
    array('label'=>'Delete Register', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->reg_id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('label'=>'Manage Register', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>View Register #<?php echo $model->reg_id; ?></h1>


  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'reg_id',
        'username',
        'mobile',
    ),
    )); ?>



 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$row,
'attributes'=>array(
        'log_id',
    'password',
            'email',
),
 )); ?>
```

Comment: Are the values being correctly saved into the database?

Comment: yes.it was inserted successfully

Comment: Can you add the code you are having in view.php?

Comment: I have got answer.i just included foreach($model->logins as $row) {   
}  and   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data'=>$row,
 'attributes'=>array(
            'log_id',
  'password',
                'email',
 ),
)); ?>

Comment: thank u for showing interst on my question

Comment: @AnjuMurali hi i'm having same issue... can you tell me on which places u have added this loop - foreach($model->logins as $row) { } ??? Need your help..